# Swift Alamofire JSON Parsing

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I'm making JSON parsing with Alamofire. I can get data from web service. I want to set label. I can print any data with "print()" function. But i can not set to label. Please help me.

My code is here.

```
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "url").validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let jsonObject = JSON(value)

                // this row is working.
                print(jsonObject["Title"].stringValue)
                // i can not print to label here
                if let titleValue = jsonObject["Title"].string {
                    self.newsTitleLabel.text = titleValue
                }


            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }

//print result:
Bolu Dağı'nda bayram tatili yoğunluğu
//if blok:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Try `self.newsTitleLabel.text = jsonObject["Title"].stringValue` directly and check if it works.

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: @Santosh Unfortunately It doesn't working

Comment: You mean the crash is on the line `self.newsTitleLabel.text = titleValue`, right? If so, `newsTitleLabel` does it exists? What it is - IBOutlet/var? Please put that code and from where you calling this service as well.

Comment: Are you sure you have hooked up your `IBOutlet` correctly? I don't seem to see anything wrong with the code. Check it once?

Comment: @Santosh is right. Thank you so much

Comment: @mc44: Glad you got your issue. Please accept my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the crash is on the line `self.newsTitleLabel.text = titleValue`, right? 
Make sure that your `newsTitleLabel` does exists either it is IBOutlet/variable.